# How can I independently move vector components (in 2D)?

Tags: graphics, manipulate, vector

Here's what may well be a simple problem that I have been having difficulty with:

There are two connected vectors, **v1** and **v2**, such that:

- **v1** begins at the origin and and ends at point *a1*
- **v2** begins at point *a1* and ends at point *a2*

The default constraints are such that moving point *a1* (via the locator at the arrowhead):

- Affects the length and direction of both *v1*  and v2,
- Does *not* affect the position of *a2*. In other words, the resultant, **v1+v2** remains unchanged.

Under other circumstances, this would be fine. However I want to implement the composition of vectors such that displacing *a1* will affect neither the length nor direction or **v2**. To do so, moving *a1* must move *a2* so that *a1-a2* remains invariant.

I want to maintain the effect of "my" moving of *a2* (It has no effect on **v1** and should not have any effect on **v1**). In other words, changing **v1** should not change **v2**, and vice-versa. That's what I mean by "independent" components.

The figure on the left is a "before" scenario.  Notice that a1 is located at {3,-1}; a2 is located at {4,1}.

The figure on the right shows the situation after a1 is displaced to {6,-1}.  Notice that **v2** has stretched and rotated slightly in a clockwise direction.

I would prefer that the **v2** would have been displayed  like the dashed black arrow is displayed. That would correspond to the idea that we changed **v1** without changing **v2**.

Any ideas about how this can be done?

[image: vectors]

Here is the code:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}],
 {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, a1}]}, Text["a1", Offset[{0, 15}, a1]],
 {Dashed, Arrow[{a1, a1 + {5, -2}}](*,Text["a3",Offset[{0,-15},a2]]*)},
 Blue, Arrow[{a1, a2}], Black, Text["a2", Offset[{0, 15}, a2]]}, 
PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}},
BaseStyle -> 16, Axes -> {True, True}],
{{a1, {-1, 3}}, {-4, -4}, {8, 8}, Locator},
{{a2, {4, 1}}, {-3, -3}, {6, 6}, Locator}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it do what you are looking for? I calculate the displacement of `a1` as `d` inside the first `Locator`'s `Dynamic`, and add this `d` to `a2` whenever `a1` is moved.

```
DynamicModule[{a1, a2, d, inita1 = {-1, 3}, inita2 = {4, 1}},
 {a1, a2} = {inita1, inita2};
 Panel@Graphics[{
    PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}],
    {Red, Dynamic@Arrow[{{0, 0}, a1}]},
    Dynamic@Text["a1", Offset[{0, 15}, a1]],
    {Dashed, Dynamic@Arrow[{a1, a1 + {5, -2}}](*,Text["a3",
     Offset[{0,-15},a2]]*)},
    {Blue, Dynamic@Arrow[{a1, a2}]},
    {Black, Dynamic@Text["a2", Offset[{0, 15}, a2]]},
    Locator[Dynamic[a1, (d = # - a1; a1 = #; a2 = a2 + d) &]],
    Locator[Dynamic[a2]]
    }, PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}, BaseStyle -> 16, 
   Axes -> {True, True}]
 ]
```

The same in `Manipulate` (I'm not sure that this is the way to do it, perhaps someone cares to correct me):

```
Manipulate[
 d = a1 - olda1;
 a2 = a2 + d;
 olda1 = a1;
 Graphics[{
   PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}],
   {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0}, a1}]}, Text["a1", Offset[{0, 15}, a1]],
   {Dashed, Arrow[{a1, a1 + {5, -2}}](*,Text["a3",Offset[{0,-15},a2]]*)},
   Blue, Arrow[{a1, a2}],
   Black, Text["a2", Offset[{0, 15}, a2]]
   },
  PlotRange -> {{-8, 8}, {-8, 8}}, BaseStyle -> 16, 
  Axes -> {True, True}],
 {{a1, {-1, 3}}, {-4, -4}, {8, 8}, Locator},
 {{a2, {4, 1}}, {-3, -3}, {6, 6}, Locator},
 {d, None},
 {{olda1, a1}, None}
 ]
```

The important point is to make the assignment to `d` **before** the assignment to `olda1`.

Comment: At first glance, it's looking very good!  I'll play around with the code and see if I can easily port it to Manipulate.

Comment: @David Yes, sorry about that, I'm pretty bad with `Manipulate`.

Comment: I'm still struggling to implement your ideas in Manipulate. I can't figure out the counterpart of `Locator[Dynamic[a1, (d = # - a1; a1 = #; a2 = a2 + d) &]]` for use in Manipulate.

Comment: @David I've tried my best, see edit!

Comment: It works really well. Just what I needed. Thanks.